# How to return to previous webview page from an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, android-webview, onbackpressed

I have a `WebView` and it will open another activity 
code in my  `Webview` client

```
if (Uri.parse(url).toString().contains(".mp3")) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Download.class);
    intent.putExtra("Link",Uri.parse(url).toString());
    intent.putExtra("Link2",myWebview.getOriginalUrl().toString());

    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Now As this intent extra will pass the value of the url from where the next `Download.class` is started

what I need is  on `onBackPressed()` it will open the url from where `Download .class` was opened

This is my`onBackPressed()` code in `Download.class`

```
Intent i = new Intent(Download.this, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer bellow code code snippet.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can we use webview in this activity as this activity has no webview in it ??

Comment: It is not possible because you need to initialize webview in particular activity.

Comment: My requirements are up there As I have one activity which contains a WebView  And another activity `Download.class` Which will get initilized only when there is .mp3 at last of url in WebView .

Comment: Now what I want is when I Press the back button from `Download.class` it should open the last page of WebView . I also had added and Intent.extra which carries the value of that url can we use that ??

Comment: As per your provided code please do not **finish()** an old activity. So please remove finish from the code.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know

Comment: By removing `finish()` nothing happens as everytime `onBackPressed()`  it initialise `mainActivity()` and there I have a webview. Which loads a specific url .